# Maui Android App Crashes in Release but Not in Debug

Tags: c#, android, maui

The app works fine in debug mode but not in release mode so we added a logger to shows where the app is crashing. (Is there a better way to trace in release mode?)  We determined that in debug mode the app steps from OnConfiguring into OnModelCreating

In debug mode, the logger confirms as much by showing "OnConfiguring 4" followed by "OnModelCreating 1".  However in release mode, the logger shows the last entry to be "OnConfiguring 4" so the app is crashing after it exits "OnConfiguring" but before it enters "OnModelCreating".

Any idea why or what could be causing the app to work in debug mode but not in release mode?

```
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        LogHelper.WriteEntry("OnConfiguring 1");
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlite($"Filename={this.DBFileName}");

        LogHelper.WriteEntry("OnConfiguring 2");            
        CustomizeConfiguration(ref optionsBuilder);
        
        LogHelper.WriteEntry("OnConfiguring 3");
        base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);

        LogHelper.WriteEntry("OnConfiguring 4");
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        LogHelper.WriteEntry("OnModelCreating 1");
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        LogHelper.WriteEntry("OnModelCreating 2");
        this.UserAccessMapping(modelBuilder);
        ...
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better way to trace in release mode?

You can use [App Center Diagnostics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/) to monitor the health of your application.

App Center Diagnostics is a cloud service which can deliver the data needed to understand what happens when an app fails during testing or in the wild. The App Center Diagnostics SDK collects information about crashes and errors in your apps and uploads them to the App Center portal for analysis by the development team - eliminating the guesswork about what really happened in the app when it failed.

To enable App Center’s diagnostics for your app, make sure you have the App Center SDK integrated for your app. To learn more about App Center’s SDKs and how to add it to your app projects, please check document [SDK documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/sdk/).

For more informaiton, please check [Enabling Diagnostics in an App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/diagnostics/enabling-diagnostics)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about AppCenter.  I was able to determine that the Sqlite file doesn't exists.  If thought that Database.Migrate() ensure the database is created and all migrations are applied.  So it must be a permission issue but where to look since it works in Debug just not in Release mode.

Comment: Do you have error logs now?

Comment: You can try adding Appcenter to your app and republishing it so that the app can report your error log file.

Comment: Yes, I am getting a FileNotFoundException.  The Sqlite DB is not able to be created.  I verified this with the File.Exists which return false.  Want permission is needed to create the file?  Note that is works Database.Migrate does create the file in Debug mode.

Comment: Could you please post the full log of this problem?

Comment: Are you referring to the Stack Traces?  BTW, I am getting a different error now: System.ArgumentNullException

Comment: System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument )
System.Linq.Enumerable.Count[IReadOnlyForeignKey](IEnumerable`1 source)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalPropertyExtensions.GetDefaultColumnName(IReadOnlyProperty property)
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.RelationalPropertyExtensions.GetDefaultColumnName(IReadOnlyProperty property, StoreObjectIdentifier& storeObject)

Comment: Can you post the code related to this problem?

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/vbhbvz6hczm8lj4r0it9i/TestCode.zip?rlkey=dbw3s90slkge9fu3bnvn4tyqs&dl=0

Comment: See above.  You should be able to see it run in debug but not in release.